# EE v2 to v5 upgrade SQL error when selecting channel for editing an entry

Tags: sql, upgrade, expressionengine

The upgrade from v2 to v5 proceeded without error, as did upgrading several plugins, however when in the control panel and I select 'Edit' > and filter by a channel I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column ‘channel_id’ in where clause is ambiguous:

Code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.author_id, m.screen_name 
FROM (exp_channel_titles t) 
LEFT JOIN exp_members m ON m.member_id = t.author_id 
WHERE channel_id = 83 
ORDER BY screen_name asc
```

Any help identifying the cause of this error and providing a fix would be very much appreciated

Note: I understand what the error means and how to fix it, what I need to know is what is going wrong and how to fix it in relation to the framework that it's used in Expression Engine.

Answer (score -1):

You have `channel_id` as a column both in your `exp_channel_titles` and your `exp_member` table, and the query handler just cannot guess which one it needs to use.

The solution is to either use `t.channel_id` or `exp_members.channel_id` instead of just `channel_id`, so your query will be more specific. You will need to determine which one is the correct one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering, I understand what the error means and how to fix it, what I need to know is what is going wrong and how to fix it in relation to the framework that it's used in.

Comment: @wot I'm not a user of that framework, but the problem boils down to the ambiguity. You will need to take a look at the point which ends up generating this query and make sure there is no such ambiguity.